# Sub-domain is not working properly

Tags: subdomain, cpanel

I want to create a sub-domain in my `cpanel`. But It's not working.
[image]

If i go to my `url`It's `show server not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have DNS A record set for primary domain and sub domain in the respective primary domain DNS zone file , you can view the records in Edit DNS zone option in WHM.